# Lists and Databinding between MainForm and ChildForm with Usercontrol Layover

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, combobox, datalist

So I have a Main Form when they click a button, a new form pops up with a user control over the form. The user control contains 2 dropdown or comboboxes that I want information in. Inside the Main Form, I have 2 lists that I want to me made access to the new form with the usercontrol on top.

Comment: You need to ask a question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.